# How do I randomly select a variable from a list, and then re assign it to another variable?

Tags: python, list, random, assign

I want to make a mastermind game im sure you all know what it is, some kind of GCSE style python number guessing game. it should ask you for a number, select a number and then tell you if you guessed any correctly but im having trouble assigning that randomly selected number to "x" perhaps.

I am pretty new to python as you can see.

```py
numberseasy = ['1244', '1354', '2355', '2366', '2609', '0010', '1234', '8873', '7775', '2512', '0293', '9463', '9901',
               '6272', '0629']
numbershard = ['25356', '86025', '67390', '96873', '01255', '77654', '96756', '88742', '09564', '12345', '19455',
               '35656', '20967', '32570']

print("welcome to mastermind!")
gamemode = input("please select gamemode: easy, hard")
if gamemode == "easy":
    (random.choice(numberseasy)) = x
    print("easy was selected")
    print("im thinking of a number, try to guess a one digit integer each time to work out the number im thinking of i")
    print("will tell you if you have one correct")
    first = input("please enter a number")
```

Answer (score 2):

Variable assignments go from left to right. You just need `x = random.choice(numberseasy)`.

Comment: @StealthReb You're welcome. If you're satisfied with any of the given answers, you should mark one as correct!

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a `.lower()` to the input string for text. This would allow the text to be entered in any capital letters.

As mentioned with blorgon's answer, you must have the variables on the left-hand side and the input on the right. In python, it is right to left such as `cake = True` or `food = "cake"`.

```py
numberseasy = ['1244', '1354', '2355', '2366', '2609', '0010', '1234', '8873', '7775', '2512', '0293', '9463', '9901',
               '6272', '0629']
numbershard = ['25356', '86025', '67390', '96873', '01255', '77654', '96756', '88742', '09564', '12345', '19455',
               '35656', '20967', '32570']

print("welcome to mastermind!")
gamemode = input("please select gamemode: easy, hard")
if gamemode.lower() == "easy":
    x = random.choice(numberseasy)
    print("easy was selected")
    print("im thinking of a number, try to guess a one digit integer each time to work out the number im thinking of i")
    print("will tell you if you have one correct")
    first = input("please enter a number")
```